Find duplicate records in lwc
Perform duplicate detection in lwc.
Here trying to find the duplicate record by comparing the existing records. Is there any other way to detect the duplication using lwc component?
js:
// detect duplicate
    async checkForDuplicateBankAccount()
    {
        let existingBankAccounts;
        try {
            existingBankAccounts = await this.handlerAddBankAccount(); 
            console.log('existingBankAccounts ',existingBankAccounts);
        } catch(error) {
            console.error('Error fetching existing bank accounts:', error);
            return false; 
        }
        const isDuplicate = existingBankAccounts.some(account => {
            return account.BankAccountNumber__c === this.bankDetails.BankAccountNumber__c &&
                   account.BankBranchNumber__c === this.bankDetails.BankBranchNumber__c &&
                   account.Name === this.bankDetails.Name; 
        });
           
        return isDuplicate;
    }


Why not use the standard functionality? It has a supporting class: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesResult.htm
